# Sql query for getting user parametar from database

Tags: sql, if-statement, plsql

I have column date_check and user in parametar form enters S to check is that column null or is not null.
So i think its should go something like this but I need your help

```
select date_check 
from tableA
if :parametar='S' then give me date_check where date_check is not null
```

so here I don't know how to write correct syntax of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select date_check 
from tableA
where (:parametar='S' AND date_check IS NOT NULL)
OR date_check IS NULL
```

If `parametar` is `S` then returns not null value date_check, otherwise it returns null

Comment: thats correct but how could I when i get dates to convert them into to text
example
21.1.2015 to display text A instead of date , something like alias

Comment: @mikrimouse I'm not sure if I undertsand you correctly, I think sth like this `case when date='21.1.2015' then 'A' else `X``

Comment: i get tons of dates and i can do specific dates, just to mark all dates with check in for example.

Comment: @mikrimouse I don't know what you mean so I can't help you. Try to prepare new question with example data and desired output than we can kelp you.

Comment: http://imgur.com/GQw3phU , i get these dates  and i dont want to see dates just some sample text which i want.

Comment: @mikrimouse Do you wan to show different text for different data?

Comment: No, same text for every date

Comment: @mikrimouse Instead of `select date_check ` you can write `select "sample text" `

Comment: "sample_text": invalid identifier
whole query :
select "sample_text"
from tableA
where :parametar='S' and date_check is not null

Comment: select CONCAT('text ', date_check) something like this but without date

Comment: Try with single quote with alias `select 'sample text' as col`

Comment: @mikrimouse I hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_check FROM tableA WHERE parametar='S' AND date_check IS NOT NULL
```

Explanation: Select every row in the column `date_check` in the table `tableA` where the column `parametar` equals the character `S` and where the cell in column `date_check` is not empty/null.